# HRESULT: 0x80040154

Tags: .net, activexobject

I create win application by vs2008 and use `dsoframer.ocx` to view word document.

This application work ok in my machine, but when I created setup file and installed it in another PC Windows XP SP3 I recieved error:

```
HRESULT: 0x80040154
```

Answer (score 2):

0x80040154 is the **Class not Registered error**.

You need to register the ocx control on other machine where you are getting this error. How did you created the setup? The setup module created by Visual Studio has dependency installation module, where you need to specify which ActiveX controls/Dlls you are using and that need to be registered.

Comment: "dsoframer.ocx" already installed with setup. i created setup by vs.net

Comment: Could be others.  Is Office installed on that machine?